# Is it better to use !! or history?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

I've found out the useful shortcut `!!` which can be used
when you forget `sudo` before the command.
You'll easily type

```
$ sudo !!
```

I've been doing this another way for a long time with <kbd>up arrow</kbd>,
<kbd>ctrl + home</kbd> and type `sudo`. The advantage is, that you see
the command.

Would you recommend to change the habit and use rather `!!` and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways have their pros and cons as you and Julie have noticed. But the really best solution is to use both of them when needed. So, when you're not sure of what `!!` will result in,

- first <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> to see what it was
- then <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
- and then `sudo !!`

There are more tricks regarding the history. This is from `man bash`.

```
Event Designators
   An  event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the his‐
   tory list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events  are  relative  to
   the current position in the history list.

   !      Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
          newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
          is enabled using the shopt builtin).
   !n     Refer to command line n.
   !-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
   !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
   !string
          Refer  to the most recent command preceding the current position
          in the history list starting with string.
   !?string[?]
          Refer to the most recent command preceding the current  position
          in  the  history  list containing string.  The trailing ? may be
          omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.
   ^string1^string2^
          Quick substitution.   Repeat  the  previous  command,  replacing
          string1  with  string2.  Equivalent to ``!!:s/string1/string2/''
          (see Modifiers below).
   !#     The entire command line typed so far.
```

To see the whole story about *history expansion*, go to `man bash` and there find the section *HISTORY EXPANSION*.

Answer (score 5):

If you just typed it and still see it, then I don't see why not use `!!` but of course don't do it blindly and end up running a previous operation that can mess things up.

I can't imagine many cases where it would be dangerous to redo the last command that way unless you smoked something really strong.